# What is a good free or cheap Team Project Management, Team Communication & Team Collaboration Script?

Tags: team-management, planning, project-management-style, project-team, multi-projects

**I have been looking for a very good Team Project Management Script that includes Team Communication, Team Collaboration, Projects & Tasks, Ability for Team Members to Assign Themselves to Projects & Tasks, Charts with Percentage Completed for Each Tasks, Multiple Projects & Multiple Tasks, Project & Task Categories & Sub-Categories, Team Member Memberships & Membership Levels, Team Member Profiles with Photo/Avatar, Team Member Portfolios (not required but would be nice) & File Uploads.**

***If anyone knows of a Free or Cheap Web Script like this, please do share with me. I would even be satisfied with a Web Platform that I do not have to upload to and install on my Web Server. Most of the Web Platforms I have found charge Per User and I cannot afford a Per User Team Project Management & Team Communication & Collaboration Platform because I have in excess of 100 Team Members so I would need something that is one fee per month that is affordable. I am looking to spend less than $100.00 Per Month with Monthly Billing for my needs if that is possible.***

**I would truly appreciate any help anyone can give me. I have searched and searched and cannot find a PHP, ASP or ASP.NET Script or Web Platform that has all or even of the features I need that is not thousands of dollars or has a per user monthly fee. If anyone happens to know of any Web Script (Programming Language is not a big deal, can use PHP, ASP, ASP.NET, Javascript, Python & ETC). Thanks for any and all help and any resources or information you may be able to provide me with!**

Comment: Software  recommendations are off-topic here. However, your question *may* fit the criteria for Recommendations Stack Exchange. Please see their help center for guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

### Open source project servers

Welcome to pm.stackexchange!

You can evaluate the following open source project servers in that order and see whether any of them will meet most of your requirements:

1. [OpenProject CE (Community Edition)](https://github.com/opf/openproject-ce)
2. [Redmine](https://www.redmine.org/)
3. [LibrePlan](https://www.libreplan.dev/)
4. [Web2project](https://web2project.net/)
5. [project-open](https://github.com/project-open)
6. [Projeqtor](https://www.projeqtor.org/en/)

It will be helpful if you can share your findings back here for the benefit of others looking for the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Web script" - and it would help if you could share some of the "expensive solutions" you have found, but won't pay for.

We use wrike.com, and that is very flexible and covers all your bases. The cost scales with the team I think, so maybe check that out.

Comment: While it's good to see users answering questions, in this case the question should actually have been closed instead of answered. If the question is closed, edited and reopened you may end up needing to rewrite or delete your answer. I hope you'll continue to help out by answering the great posts, and closing the ones that don't fit here!